# Not able to install mysql-workbench in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mysql-workbench, ubuntu-12.10

I am trying to install msyql-workbench in my ubuntu 12.10 using the following command

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench
```

but it shows the following error.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
mysql-workbench : Depends: python-all but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: mysql-utilities but it is not installable
```

I have tried

```
sudo apt-get install python-all
```

but it shows the error,

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-all : Depends: python (= 2.7.3-0ubuntu2.2) but 2.7.3-0ubuntu7 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The following command also not working

```
sudo apt-get -f install mysql-workbench
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

go to [this link](http://download.softagency.net/MySQL/Downloads/MySQLGUITools/), where all download inks are available , then search with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> for ubu1204 u will get different distributions , choose bit 32/64, then run the file using software centre, It works.

[image: mysql ubuntu distributions]

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:olivier-berten/misc 

sudo apt-get update 

sudo apt-get install  mysql-workbench
```

this worked for me [ref link](http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/12/install-mysql-workbench-5244-from-ppa.html?m=0)

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo apt-get update` and then try to install

Answer (score 0):

Try making a sudo apt-get install python-all and sudo apt-get install mysql-utilities. And then try again.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command instead:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

After that MySQL Workbench should be installed fine.

Make sure you selected Ubuntu Linux from the drop down. [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is good solution to resolve this error but i have resolved in ubuntu 16.04

You have to just copy and paste my resources.list file into your location /etc/apt/sources.list

**My resources.list file**

==========================================================================

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Beta amd64 (20150805)]/ trusty main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ trusty partner
```

==========================================================================

and after run below commands

1. sudo apt-get update
2. sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench

It will work.....